# Google Youtube API: Sharing the video from my app to youtube as Shorts

Tags: flutter, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

So, We have an app, that streams live video and the video will be trimmed to 20s after the stream is over. now we want to share that trimmed video as YouTube SHORTS to that particular user whose live stream has ended. Can we achieve this? If So, How can we do this?

I want that if any user uploads video to YouTube then it uploads to his/her account.

Also, As a company, we have many apps. Do we need to create multiple app in developer account or will 1 account be enough to handle all the different apps that we as a company have.

Comment: For your second question answer is you can have 1 account to handle for all app.